# Extract Data From Second Line of Output

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table that contains message_content. It looks like this:

```
message_content | WFUS54 ABNT 080344\r\r
                | TORLCH\r\r
                | TXC245-361-080415-\r
```

How would I extract only the 2nd line of that output(TORLCH)? I've tried to shorten the output to a certain number of characters but that ultimately doesn't provide what I want. I've also tried removing carriage returns and new lines. I am outputting my results to a CSV I could manipulate with Python, but was wondering if there's a way to do it in the query first.

Based on other examples, it seems like I could use a regular expression to maybe do this? Not sure where to start with learning that though.

Answer (score 0):

you can split the line into an array, then take the second element:

```
(string_to_array(message_content, e'\r\r'))[2]
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/MDYLXB40812